# Logs are not showing anymore ELK Stack

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, filebeat, topbeat

It's my first ELK setup and I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
Tutorial I used to set up Logstash (for jenkins), Filebeat and Topbeat:  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana-elk-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04.
I was able to see my Jenkins job logs but after a while they disapperd and the newer logs are only shown when I build the job. Topbeat was also working fine and I was able to monitor my server. What could be going wrong ?
I have tried to set `start_position=>"beginning"` and change `sincedb_path` to `/dev/null`.

Comment: Did you try to change the @timestamp filter in Kibana ? By default it only shows the data loaded during the last 15 minutes.

Comment: It did the job. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the @timestamp filter in Kibana.
By default it only shows the data loaded during the last 15 minutes.